# Compare time stamps and call a script

Tags: file, timestamp, compare

I have researched how to do this but none of the code makes any sense as my scripting skills are limited to basic tasks. I would like to write a script to compare a files create and modified date to current date in that folder and if it's older than two days call another script in different directory.

I tried to write it but not sure where to start. It seems simple enough yet confusing.

Please let me know or guide me in the direction where I will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you share the code you wrote?

Comment: I have this pseudo code but dont know how to go about it


if "%file%" is_newer_than "$DATE" (
        do nothing
) else if "%file%" is_2_days_older_than "$DATE" (
  call C:\script.bat
)

Comment: I was just looking into do the same task with power shell, would it be easier to do it that way?

Comment: so i have this [datetime](Get-ItemProperty -Path $source).LastWriteTime

Comment: how can i make it so after the output it compares the date with current and if its older then two days it calls another batch file
?

Comment: i got it to work via powershell

Comment: $fileName = "C:\Blat\blat.dll"
if ( test-path $fileName ) {
  if ( (get-item $fileName).LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).Date ) {
     exit
  
  }
  else {
    Start-Process C:\Blat\mail.bat
  }  
}
exit

Comment: but i cant get the command line to exit after the job is done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$fileName = "C:\Blat\mail.bat"
if ( test-path $fileName ) {
  if ( (get-item $fileName).LastWriteTime -ge (get-date).Date ) {
    exit

  }
  else {
    Start-Process C:\Blat\mail.bat
  }  
}
exit
```

I got it to work but i cant get the command line window to exit when needed.